# Count the first survey sent after a specific incident case resolve date

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to solve a problem in my analytical project whereas a representative gets a customer call/email and if needed they would ask for an advisor help (advise ring) and after that the representative would resolve the email/phone, henceforth sending a survey to the customer.

I want to track the first survey sent after the advise ring have been resolved only, but it does not matter if the customer opened the incident again and the representative resolved the incident without an advise ring, we would not want to count that survey.

Use case: A Representative gets an email > Pulls an advise ring > The advisor resolves it > Representative solves the email > Survey is sent (Gets counted). > Customer open the incident again > Rep solves the incident without an advise ring > Survey is sent (Does not get counted).

The problem here is that I can't track the subsequent dates for some reason.

Survey Table example

```
Incident_ID|    Survey_sent_date  | survey_id | response  | 
-----------+---------+-----+------------+------------------
3324324    | 2022-03-03 16:23:02.1|     7     |           | 
3324324    | 2022-03-03 18:32:0.1 |    14     |     N     | 
3324324    | 2022-03-04 11:32:0.1 |     9     |     Y     |
3324324    | 2022-03-05 16:23:02.1|    17     |     Y     | 
3324324    | 2022-03-11 18:31:12.1|   134     |     N     | 
3324324    | 2022-03-11 20:35:12.1|   139     |     N     |
3324324    | 2022-03-15 19:45:26.0|    29     |     Y     |
3324324    | 2022-03-17 19:45:26.0|    229    |     Y     |
```

Advise ring table

```
Incident_ID|    advise_ring_resolve_date| advise_ring_id 
-----------+---------+-----+------------+--------------
3324324    | 2022-03-11 18:30:52.1       |    247     | 
3324324    | 2022-03-15 19:30:37.0       |    143     |
```

Expected Results:

```
Incident_ID|    Survey_sent_date   | survey_id | response  | 
-----------+---------+-----+------------+------------------
   3324324 | 2022-03-11 18:31:12.1 | 134       | N         |  
   3324324 | 2022-03-15 19:45:26.0 | 29        | Y         |
```

I have tried to get the first rank of each date between each survey_sent_date and get the subsequent survey_id between the advise_ring_resolve_date and the survey_sent_date.

What I have in mind is the following:

On the advise_ring_id 247, get the survey sent on 2022-03-11 18:31:12.1 ONLY as it was immediately sent after the advise ring was resolved.

Similarly, the advise_ring_id 143 would get the survey sent on 2022-03-15 19:45:26.0 as it was immediately after the advise ring was resolved. and so on.

```
WITH surveys_sent as(
     SELECT DISTINCT 
     ss.incident_id,
     ss.survey_sent_date,
     ss.survey_id,
     ss.response,
     ROW_NUMBER OVER (PARTITION BY ss.survey_id ORDER BY ss.survey_sent_date) as req
     FROM SURVEY_TABLE SS
     WHERE ss.incident_id = '3324324'),

 advise_ring as(
     SELECT DISTINCT 
     ar.incident_id,
     ar.advise_ring_resolve_date,
     ar.advise_ring_id
     FROM ADVISE_TABLE
     WHERE ss.incient_id = '3324324')

  SELECT DISTINCT 
       finalar.case_id,
       finalss.survey_id,
       finalss.survey_sent_date
  FROM advise_ring finalar
  INNER JOIN surveys_sent finalss
  ON finalar.case_id = finalss.case_id AND finalar.advise_ring_resolve_date BETWEEN 
  finalar.advise_ring_resolve_date AND finalss.survey_sent_date
  WHERE finalss.req = 1;
```

I tried to full outer and left join the table, also tried to remove the ranking bit which did not help at all.

The full outer join provided me with a union like join where both of the columns are empty at their respective timestamp.

The desired result would having the count OR the details of the surveys sent after the first advise ring has been sent on that specific date.

Do you have any advise on the above?

Thanks!

EDIT:

I have tried to get the rank of the lowest difference between the advise ring date and the survey sent date, however it gives me duplicate values for some reason.

```
WITH base AS 
( 
  SELECT DISTINCT * 
  FROM ADVISE_TABLE
  WHERE INCIDENT_ID = 3324324
 )
SELECT *
FROM 
(
SELECT
base.advise_ring_id,
ss.survey_sent_date,
ss.survey_id,
base.advise_ring_resolve_date,
DATEDIFF(sec,ss.survey_sent_date,base.advise_ring_resolve_date) 
as time_diff
,ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY base.advise_ring_id ORDER BY 
DATEDIFF(sec,ss.survey_sent_date,base.advise_ring_resolve_date) 
DESC) as rk
FROM base
LEFT JOIN SURVEY_TABLE ss
on ss.incident_id = base.incident_id 
WHERE 
DATEDIFF(sec,ss.survey_sent_date,base.advise_ring_resolve_date) 
<=0
)
WHERE rk = 1
```

Result is from real table but different data:

```
base.advise_ring_id|Survey_sent_date  | survey_id | base.advise_ring_resolve_date| 
-----------+---------+-----+------------+------------------
    123        | 2022-12-22 16:23:02.1|     7      |     2022-12-15 13:23:02.1        | 
    333        | 2022-01-03 06:55:25.1 |    14     |     2022-12-23 18:23:02.1     | 
    333        | 2022-01-03 06:55:25.1 |    14     |     2022-12-29 11:23:02.1     |
```

Basically from the result the top 2 only should be included not the third one, so by each date.

Comment: Using the sample data above, what are the expected results?

Comment: @SOS
Getting these values only

3324324    | 2022-03-11 18:31:12.1|   134     |     N     | 
3324324    | 2022-03-15 19:45:26.0|    29     |     Y     |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I *think* something like this should work. Use [LAG](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html) to get the *previous* survey date based on the current row. Then search for any `Advise_Ring` records between the previous and current survey date range. Finally use ROW_NUMBER() to rank the `Advise_Ring` records and return the first one.

> ```
> WITH surveys AS (
>    SELECT *
>           , LAG(Survey_Sent_Date, 1) OVER( 
>               PARTITION BY Incident_Id ORDER BY Survey_Sent_Date
>           ) AS Prev_Survey_Sent_Date
>    FROM   Survey_Table
> )
> SELECT t.Incident_ID
>        , t.Survey_sent_date
>        , t.survey_id
>        , t.response
>        , t.advise_ring_id 
> FROM (
>        SELECT s.Incident_ID
>              , s.Survey_sent_date
>              , s.survey_id
>              , s.response
>              , ar.advise_ring_id
>              , ar.advise_ring_resolve_date
>              , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
>                 PARTITION BY s.survey_id 
>                 ORDER BY ar.advise_ring_resolve_date, ar.advise_ring_id
>              ) AS advise_row_num
>        FROM   surveys s INNER JOIN Advise_Ring ar 
>                 ON s.Incident_ID = ar.Incident_ID
>                 AND s.Prev_Survey_Sent_Date < ar.advise_ring_resolve_date
>                 AND s.Survey_Sent_Date > ar.advise_ring_resolve_date
>      ) t
> WHERE  t.advise_row_num = 1
> ORDER BY t.Survey_Sent_Date         
>
> ;
> ```

**Results:**

| Incident_ID | Survey_sent_date | survey_id | response | advise_ring_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 7496137492 | 2021-12-22 15:25:48 | 5245 | Y | 1 |
| 7496137492 | 2022-01-03 06:55:25 | 4613 | Y | 12 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2c4cc70500314b055095313e45374c92)*

Comment: Table 'db_793469261.Advise_Ring' doesn't exist

Also, I have managed to get some result, can you look at the edits above?

Comment: My example used `Advise_Table` instead of `ADVISE_TABLE`, but use whatever case is appropriate for you db.

Comment: I have added more data, not sure why its not working:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=06327ffd95573232c57c733a74545764

Comment: Thanks! I think it's a small bug in dbfiddle. The statements were actually failing because 7496137492 is too big for the declared type `int`, but it didn't throw an error. [Using bigint fixes it](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ada12e2494cb3a68f5af5521956d1e8b).  Anyway, let me take a look now...

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a5042358cc984b6c992bf4707c76fc47

I have added bigint YES I think that solved it, but only returns 3 ROWS Only. (NEW data) and it should return 3 different survey IDs, 5245 and 4613 but it returns 4613 twice instead of having 311 as the final one

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=51fd6da5bbe6e24f40ca29015bf157c1

Comment: Correction** 2 only and 4613 was twice

Comment: With the new data, which id's do you expect and why?

Comment: After fixing the duplicate, based on the timestamps, I'd expect it to return only 2 records: 5245 and 4613  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=31428782313514ab8f492f685e5964e8

Comment: I would expect the same results as you did! You're a genius. I pity myself for not knowing the Lag function..

Comment: Heh, don't feel bad. I ignored window functions like LAG for a while too ... until I realized how useful they were! Anyway, glad it's all working :-)